# How to create templates with vue-router?

Tags: vue-router

In my app I have 2 templates: BgTopFoot and EmptyWhite. When switching between routes that share the same template **that template should not be reloaded**.
So far I have managed to do it like this:

```
// router.ts
{
  path: '/presets',
  name: 'presets',
  component: () => import('@/pages/PresetsPage.vue'),
  meta: {
    template: 'BgTopFoot'
  }
},
{
  path: '/logs',
  name: 'logs',
  component: () => import('@/pages/LogsPage.vue'),
  meta: {
    template: 'EmptyWhite'
}

// App.vue
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <BgTopFoot v-if="$route.meta.template === 'BgTopFoot'">
    <component :is="Component" />
  </BgTopFoot>

  <EmptyWhite v-if="$route.meta.template === 'EmptyWhite'">
    <component :is="Component" />
  </EmptyWhite>
</router-view>
```

My templates have a `<slot>` where I pass the contents of the route as a component.

I feel like I'm hacking it with this solution.

Is there a better or more standard way to do this?
For example, is there a dedicated way to pass a template option in the router definition?